# Switch Driver Control between Windows Desktop app and Chrome

Tags: c#, selenium, appium, desktop-application, coded-ui-tests

Scenario : Windows app that open a chrome browser

1. Open Windows app
2. Click on a boutton, --> Open a browser separately
3. Native_app and Chrome_app work at the same time
   I just want to switch between chrome and my Native_App, but I don’t now how.

> 

```
    static WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> Driver;
    static IWebDriver _seleniumDriver;

    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void PrepareForTestinNuances(TestContext testContext)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ClassInitialize");

        AppiumOptions capNuances = new AppiumOptions();
        capNuances.AddAdditionalCapability("app", @"PATH_APP");
        capNuances.AddAdditionalCapability("appArguments", "--Environment=development.me");
        capNuances.AddAdditionalCapability("platformName", "Windows");
        Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Application Driver\WinAppDriver.exe");
        SessionNuances = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), capNuances);

    }

[TestMethod]
    public void TestMonAssitance()
    {

        Debug.WriteLine("Verification");
        Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        Driver.FindElementByName("QUESTIONS");
        var elemento= Driver.FindElementByXPath("//Window/Group[1]/Custom[1]/Custom[1]/Button[1]");
        elemento.Click();
        _seleniumDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("Www.google.com");
        var compte = _seleniumDriver.FindElement(By.Id("search"));
        compte.SendKeys("Hello");
```

Comment: What do you mean by "switch between" the two applications?